# Why is the text disappearing?

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

I created a new web application, which gives me a master page. I changed the foreground color and the background color of the header, and the text isn't showing anymore. Why? Isn't the foreground color the text color? If not – how *do* I control the text color?

I'm doing this in design view.

I now see that running it – the text *is* shown. But not when I'm in design mode. But it *is* shown if I don't change the div's (on which the text is) backcolor.

How do I see the text again?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            color: #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET <span class="style1">Application</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm doing this in design view.

Comment: Design view isn't the only view available.  People are asking for more information to help you, but you so far are refusing to provide any additional info.

Comment: @TLS I'm a beginner, and I don't know what I'm supposed to show.

Comment: @ispiro-From the beginning you're saying that you are trying to add in the design view ie. nothing but your html page where you're trying to add the color.Please post that code.

Comment: @DotNetter Do you mean you can see the text of the header in design view? (I don't.)

Comment: @ispiro-Now you can see my edit with a preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a VS bug.

For more details on how to duplicate it, see [Why is visual web developer working the way it is (hiding text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992564/why-is-visual-web-developer-working-the-way-it-is-hiding-text) .

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `site.css` file and you can add a color to the "title" and you will be having default as

```
.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    color: #FF66FF ! important;
}
```

You can add a color element here or from the design view you can specify it as

```
<title style="color: #FF66FF ! important;">Hello Asp.Net</title>
```

And this is the result you'll get[image]:

This is your output and its working perfect as seen below:

[image]

Comment: See update that I've figured out that the problem is just that it's not shown in the design view. It _is_ showing correctly when executed.

Comment: try to delete the aspx file and add a new one and check once again.

Comment: I'm working on the "Site.Master" and I can't find an aspx file for that. Only for "About" and "Default" which I haven't touched.

Comment: if not you can do one more thing go to design view select the span text and click F4 and on the left side you will find properties for span and in that you'll find class which has a drop down list and from that select style1.Then it will apply that color to the text.

Comment: Gotta go now. +1 For helping, though. Thanks.

Comment: @ispiro-You're welcome.Finally you got it.That's what we need :)

Answer (score 0):

Of the `<title>` element? You can't change the color of that element.

Comment: No. I meant the large text at the top of the page. It's showing me "h1.style1".

Comment: @ispiro-That is the title and you can check my answer for that.And I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net controls you use ForeColor, like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Id="MyLabel" ForeColor="Red"
```

in css you use the color property, like:

```
#MyLabel
{
   color:Red;
}
```

If you want to style it inline, directly on the element with css syntax, you could use:

```
<h1 style="color:Red">
  My red title
</h1>
```

Comment: I'm doing this in design view.